# Xamarin UWP app, run a batch file during installation in client machine

Tags: c#, batch-file, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

We have a Xamarin UWP app currently in beta distribution.
I would like to know how can I run a command prompt with some registry edit for 'authhost' with admin privileges right after app setup?

Context:

ADAL library fails to launch the authentication window in certain cases. For this to work I need to run a registry command in command prompt to enable authhost to use private networks. I can't ask each of my client to run this command, so I would like run it during app setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to (and shouldn't) hack the permission authhost for production use. That is documented explicitly for debugging to loosen security so Fiddler can intercept to web conversation.

In production an app which calls WebAuthenticationBroker with appropriate arguments and capabilities will get an authhost with appropriate private network capabilities.

From ADAL do this by setting passing the UseCorporateNetwork argument as documented in [Integrating a Windows Universal application with Azure AD](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-windows-store/)

> Step 5 (Optional): Enable Windows Integrated Authentication when using
>   a federated Azure AD tenant
>
> Out of the box, this sample is not configured to work with Windows
>   Integrated Authentication (WIA) when used with a federated Azure
>   Active Directory domain. To work with WIA the application manifest
>   must enable additional capabilities. These are not configured by default > for this sample because applications requesting the Enterprise 
>   Authentication or Shared User Certificates capabilities require a
>   higher level of verification to be accepted into the Windows Store,
>   and not all developers may wish to perform the higher level of
>   verification.
>
> To enable Windows Integrated Authentication, in Package.appxmanifest,
>   in the Capabilities tab, enable: * Enterprise Authentication * Private
>   Networks (Client & Server) * Shared User Certificates
>
> Plus uncomment the following line of code:
>   authContext.UseCorporateNetwork = true;

To the direct question: Windows doesn't run code or script while deploying your app. If you are side-loading your MDM may be able to do so before or after it does the actual app deploy. How will be MDM specific.

Comment: Thanks for the response Rob, I believe the only thing that I missed was I had authContext.UseCorporateNetwork = true commented out. Really thankful for your quick response. Hope this fixes the issue for our users.